# SSISDB says package is running but its not

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an issue from time to time with SSIS where my package just seems to die. The Execution report says the package is running, the catalog.executions view has NULL for end_time, so the SSISDB thinks the package is running. But there is no activity on the database that the package is working on, and no resource usage on the server, so I'm pretty sure the package is not running.
Also, the last message in the catalog.operation_messages view is over 12 hours old (and it is just an informational message, no errors reported).

How can I determine what is happening here? Is there another log file that could help? Or some other way to trace what is happening?

My SQL version is 2014 Enterprise.

Comment: Right click on the catalog and check "Active Operations". Use `sp_who2` to see if SSIS is still logged in

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer to my question. The Windows application log reveals the problem:

> The SSIS Execution Process could not write to the IS catalog:
>   IEDC-PTF-PSV007:SSISDB Error details: Unable to add new messages to
>   the table of operation messages.:There is insufficient system memory
>   in resource pool 'default' to run this query.; at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ISServerHelper.AppendEventMessage(SqlCommand
>   cmd, Int64 operationId, Int32 message_type, DateTimeOffset
>   message_time, Int16 message_source, String message_text, Nullable 1
>   extendedInfoId, String packageName, String packageLocationType, String
>   packagePathFull, String eventName, String messageSource, String
>   messageSrcId, String subComponentName, String packagePath, String
>   executionPath, UInt32 threadId, Nullable`1 messageCode, Int64&
>   eventMessageId) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.BasicEventInfo.WriteInternal(SqlCommand
>   sqlCommand) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.CompositeLog.WriteInternal(SqlCommand
>   sqlCommand) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.Loggable.Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ISServerExec.ILoggable.Write(SqlConnection
>   conn)

So the package was unable to write to the database and therefore failed, but it still appears to be running because it could not write the status back to the DB!

My SSISDB has grown to 200GB so I think this is causing a problem. I am going to reduce the size and lower the retention period.